# How do i import until row 5 using laravel excel version 3.1?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

how to import file data excel until row 5 using laravel excel 3.1? [excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLFGS.png)  [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy5LS.png)

Comment: At what point in importing 5 rows did you have issues? Please add your code to the question not via an image.

Answer (score 0):

When you only want to return the first x rows of a sheet, you can use `limit()`.

```
    public function limit(): int
    {
        return 10;
    }
```

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/2423